# Function give value of 0

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the value for function of test1 and test2, but when I call them in Excel it give value of 0

I already gave number value = 5

These are the codes:

```
Option Explicit

Public number As Double

Public Sub input_variable()
    number = 4.2
End Sub

Function Test1() As Double
    Test1 = number * number
End Function

Function Test2() As Double
    Test2 = number * number * number
End Function
```

Comment: Probably because you formatted one of your numbers as a range? Firstly, use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your sheet, and make sure you declare all of your variables.

Comment: Is `Number` a public variable?

Comment: Are you sure input_variable is called before test1 or test2?
Also. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

i want to use the variable (number) as a global variable that have value that can be use in all function
is it possible?

Comment: I have updated my answer below. The reason your value is zero is likely because you are not calling `Sub input_variable`. If this isn't called, then your value is never being set, meaning the value is `Empty`, aka `0`. (`0 x 0 = 0`) What you want to do is convert your `Sub` to a `Function` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are going to call your Subroutine `input_variable`, your value `Number` will not be set. If you do not intend on calling this Sub, then you need to convert it to a `Function`

```
Option Explicit

Function Number() As Double
    Number = 4.2
End Function

Function Test1() As Double
    Test1 = Number * Number
End Function

Function Test2() As Double
    Test2 = Number * Number * Number
End Function
```

Comment: Worth to mention that you will need to change `Long` into `Double` or something if `Range("A1")` contains floating numbers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i want to use the variable (number) as a global variable that have value that can be use in all function is it possible?

Comment: @KDavis not really because i need to refer the cell that contain the value number

Comment: @SomeProgrammer So it's not a public/global variable you are needing as you stated in your last comment, but an absolute reference to a cell? Can you reference the cell in your question that you are referring to?

Comment: @KDavis okay
i already edit my main post into simpler problem

i assign number as 4.2
if i type 
=test1()

in a cell, i should be show 17.64
but it show 0 now

Comment: @SomeProgrammer You first have to run the `Sub input_variable`. You can do this a number of ways. But the value for `Number` will not be set until you run the `Sub input_variable` first. Or you can get rid of the `Sub` altogether and just make Number a `Function` as well

Answer (score 2):

test1/2 can't understand what Number is, as Number is out of scope. you shoul include the Number in functions as below

```
Function test1()
Number = Range("number")
test1 = Number * Number
End Function

Function test2()
Number = Range("number")
test2 = Number * Number * Number
End Function
```

Comment: the thing is that i want to use the same variable (number) in many function
if i include it in each function, i think it will be a waste?

can i put the variable (number) outside as global that can be use in all function?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer This is the safest way you do it and no waste. If you read the variable only once globally then imagine if the value in range A1 changes but it will not change in the global variable, so you will always calculate with the old value. Reading the Range in every function is not bad. An alternative would be read it in your main function and give it as a parameter as KDavis showed in his answer.